# How to cache Elixir / Phoenix on CircleCI?

Tags: continuous-integration, elixir, phoenix-framework, circleci, circleci-2.0

Currently, my `CircleCI 2.0` caching strategy for `Elixir` projects is as follows:

```
  - restore_cache:
      keys:
        - v1-mix-cache-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "mix.lock" }}
        - v1-mix-cache-{{ .Branch }}
        - v1-mix-cache
        - v1-build-cache-{{ .Branch }}
        - v1-build-cache

  - save_cache:
      key: v1-mix-cache-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "mix.lock" }}
      paths: deps
  - save_cache:
      key: v1-mix-cache-{{ .Branch }}
      paths: deps
  - save_cache:
      key: v1-mix-cache
      paths: deps
  - save_cache:
      key: v1-build-cache-{{ .Branch }}
      paths: _build
  - save_cache:
      key: v1-build-cache
      paths: _build
```

However, from time to time, it causes errors like that:

```
===> Compiling certifi

=ERROR REPORT==== 12-Jul-2018::15:37:40 ===
Loading of /home/circleci/project/_build/test/lib/parse_trans/ebin/parse_trans.beam failed: badfile

=ERROR REPORT==== 12-Jul-2018::15:37:40 ===
beam/beam_load.c(1863): Error loading module parse_trans:
  This BEAM file was compiled for a later version of the run-time system than 20.
  To fix this, please recompile this module with an 20 compiler.
  (Use of opcode 162; this emulator supports only up to 159.)

===> Compiling src/certifi.erl failed
```

Sometimes we get:

```
 ** (UndefinedFunctionError) function :hackney.request/5 is undefined (module :hackney is not available)

/home/circleci/project/_build/test/lib/hackney/ebin/hackney.beam failed: :badfile

 12:44:02.665 [error] beam/beam_load.c(1863): Error loading module hackney:
   This BEAM file was compiled for a later version of the run-time system than 20.
   To fix this, please recompile this module with an 20 compiler.
   (Use of opcode 162; this emulator supports only up to 159.)
```

Everything is, of course, a matter of caching, because when we re-run the build without cache, everything works as expected.

This doesn't happen each time, but from time to time, with different errors.

Do you have any reliable caching strategy for `Elixir` projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to do:

```
  - restore_cache:
      keys:
        - v{{ .Environment.CACHE_VERSION }}-mix-cache-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "mix.lock" }}
  - restore_cache:
      keys:
        - v{{ .Environment.CACHE_VERSION }}-build-cache-{{ .Branch }}

  - save_cache:
      key: v{{ .Environment.CACHE_VERSION }}-mix-cache-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "mix.lock" }}
      paths: deps
  - save_cache:
      key: v{{ .Environment.CACHE_VERSION }}-build-cache-{{ .Branch }}
      paths: _build
```

Answer (score 1):

*disclaimer: I'm a CircleCI Developer Advocate*

I see 1 issue and one potential issue here.

First, you don't want to save the cache multiple times for partial keys. Restoring cache keys works by partial matching. When you're saving cache, use the full key name once and that's it. Restoring cache will martially match it when it needs to.

Second, does Elixir support partial cache? I don't use it myself so I don't know it well enough yet. If it doesn't, you may only want to restore the full cache key and not any partial keys.

For my first point:

```
  - restore_cache:
      keys:
        - v1-mix-cache-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "mix.lock" }}
        - v1-mix-cache-{{ .Branch }}
        - v1-mix-cache
        - v1-build-cache-{{ .Branch }}
        - v1-build-cache

  - save_cache:
      key: v1-mix-cache-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "mix.lock" }}
      paths: deps
  - save_cache:
      key: v1-build-cache-{{ .Branch }}
      paths: _build
```

and for my second point:

```
  - restore_cache:
      keys:
        - v1-mix-cache-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "mix.lock" }}
        - v1-build-cache-{{ .Branch }}

  - save_cache:
      key: v1-mix-cache-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "mix.lock" }}
      paths: deps
  - save_cache:
      key: v1-build-cache-{{ .Branch }}
      paths: _build
```

Comment: The problem I get is still:

`10:08:04.821 [error] Loading of /home/circleci/project/_build/test/lib/hackney/ebin/hackney.beam failed: :badfile
     
     10:08:04.822 [error] beam/beam_load.c(1863): Error loading module hackney:
       This BEAM file was compiled for a later version of the run-time system than 20.
       To fix this, please recompile this module with an 20 compiler.
       (Use of opcode 162; this emulator supports only up to 159.)`

Comment: @KamilLelonek It looks like your cache contains a build that used a different version of Erlang/OTP. Try breaking the cache by bumping the version number of the key.